# Upload images with CKEditor and show img src in html ( editor data ) - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5, multiparty

Here's how it looks inside the code:

```
...

 <CKEditor
    editor={ ClassicEditor }
    data={this.state.htmlString}
    config={{
        ckfinder: {                               
            uploadUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/upload',
            
        }}}
    onChange={ ( event, editor ) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        this.handleSubjectChange(data);
        console.log( { event, editor, data } );
        console.log(this.state.htmlString);
    } }
/>

...
```

Inside server.js I am using Multiparty to upload images:

```
...

import express from 'express'

import multiparty from 'connect-multiparty'

const app = express();

const MultipartyMiddleware = multiparty({uploadDir:'src/blogs/images'})

app.post('/upload',MultipartyMiddleware,(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.files.upload)
})

...
```

[image: This is how it looks in console.log]

From console.log (whole object):

```
Object
data: "<p>sasasa</p><figure class="image"><img></figure>"
editor: rb {_context: En, id: "ef7e9d1eac6bb296e04f9d806d027c180", config: on, plugins: Tn, locale: Sn, …}
event: cn {source: ec, name: "change:data", path: Array(1), stop: ƒ, off: ƒ}
__proto__: Object
```

Image gets uploaded in the folder:
[image]

**Issue: I can't get to show img src in editor data**

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by sending a response from the server that contains the path url of the uploaded image.

```
app.post('/upload',MultipartyMiddleware,(req,res)=>{
    var imagePath = req.files.upload.path;
    
    res.status(200).json({
       uploaded:true,
       url: `${imagePath}`
   })
})
```